# Can't create a Object

Tags: java, android, object, parameters, constructor

I have an app with multiple classes:

> MenuActivity, MenuThread, MenuView, MenuBot, MenuBall.

In the class "MenuView" I declare all the ib objects I need:

```
this.ball = new MenuBall(this, bot1);    
this.bot1 = new MenuBot1(this, ball);    
this.thread = new MenuThread(this,bot1,ball);
```

As you can see i didn't create yet the object bot1 but i already use it as a parameter in the object ball, which gives me the error.

Thank you for trying to help me !

Comment: Circular dependency! Bad way to do it!

Comment: What are you trying to do with `bot1` in `MenuBall`'s constructor? You can't use objects before you create them- Java can't predict what the object will be in the future.

Comment: @SanPonko Bot1 should change its own direction then. Then Ball doesn't need to know about Bot1. But it would be even better to keep collision detection away from entity classes all together.

Comment: @vakio but the Bot1 should  NOT change the direction of himself the Ball should.

Comment: @Tanis.7x Bot1 need to get the parameters od the Ball to detect if they collide. And the Ball is changing the direction if this is the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change (or add other) constructors of MenuBall and MenuBot1.
Thus, for example:

```
public class MenuBall {
    private MenuBot1 menuBot1;
    (...)

    // this constructor doesn't need a MenuBot1 object.
    public MenuBall(MenuView menuView) {
        (...)
    }

    // setter for the menuBot1
    public void setMenuBot1(MenuBot1 menuBot1) {
        this.menuBot1 = menuBot1;
    }

    (...)
}

public class MenuBot1 {
    private MenuBall menuBall;
    (...)

    // this constructor doesn't need a MenuBall object.
    public MenuBot1(MenuView menuView) {
        (...)
    }

    // setter for the menuBall
    public void setMenuBall(MenuBall menuBall) {
        this.menuBall = menuBall;
    }

    (...)
}
```

Then in MenuView class:

```
ball = new MenuBall(this);
bot1 = new MenuBot1(this);
ball.setMenuBot1(bot1);
bot1.setMenuBall(ball);
thread = new MenuThread(this, bot1, ball);
(...)
```